# why python doesn't have a main function?

Tags: python, programming-languages, program-entry-point

Why python doesn't have a main function?

I mean, almost every language has a main function, including java:

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```

c++:

```
int main(){}
```

Why python doesn't have one?
Should we consider this as a good sign or bad sign? Should we consider this as an advantage or disadvantage?

Comment: You can refer to [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-doesnt-python-have-a-main-function-3afe6a8d093). Hope it will give you more insights into your question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is an interpreter that means it executes the code line by line from top, so it doesn't matter where the main() function is. An interpreter can be slower than a compiler but editing and changing the code is easier. You can find out more information of this here: https://www.programiz.com/article/difference-compiler-interpreter